# consultar si tabla posee registro Angular 6

Tags: angular

Hola quiero preguntar al inicio de mi aplicación web si una tabla del backend posee 0 registros. Estoy trabajando en angular. `ventaServi` es el servicio

```
this.listSeccTemp();//refresco la tabla
if (this.ventaServi.listSeccTemp.length == 0){
  console.log('esta vacia')

      }else{
        console.log('tiene archivo')
      }
```

en el servicio tengo asi :

```
  listSeccTemp(){
return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/sistemaKiosco/server/secciones/listSeccTemp.php');
```

y el php (backend) :
un simple

```
SELECT * FROM secciones_temp
```

desde ya Gracias .

Comment: estas usando un solo signo de `=` lo cual sirve para asignación y tu lo que tratas de hacer es comparar, lo cual se debería hacer con `==`

Comment: Perfecto dejo de darme error poniendo "==" pero ahora me arroja que siempre esta vacía la tabla.                                        
    this.listSeccTemp();//refrezco la tabla
    if (this.ventaServi.listSeccTemp.length == 0){
      console.log('esta vacia')

          }else{
            console.log('tiene archivo')
          }

Comment: Llamar así a ese método no te va a funcionar, si estás usando Angular deberías aprender a usar Observables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar un .subscribe, ya que `this.http.get` retorna una observable:

```
this.ventaServi.listSeccTemp().subscribe((response:any) => {

    //tu codigo aquí

});
```

Comment: this.http.get retorna un Observable

Comment: Corregido!!! Gracias crack